# split a string on multiple delimiters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql that returns the example string below:

**Input** `PKIND:BCMOX:10048301-`

**output** `BCMOX:10048301`

I need to write code the first substring the string on `-` then split it on `:` and return the 2 & 3 item (`BCMOX:10048301`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string format is consistent and you want to extract everything after the first `:` until the first occurrence of `-`, use a combination of `substr` and `instr`.

```
select substr(col, instr(col,':')+1, instr(col,'-')-instr(col,':')-1)
from yourtable
where instr(col,':') > 0 and instr(col,'-') > 0 --to get the rows which have these 2 characters
```

Answer (score 0):

The REGEXP_SUBSTR version. Return everything between the first colon and the first hyphen.

```
select regexp_substr('PKIND:BCMOX:10048301-', ':(.*)-', 1, 1, NULL, 1) from dual;
```